# MEF Import fails in Windows Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, mef

I am having an issue in the MEF composition within my Windows service

The below classes are the partial classes that inherit from the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess

<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class svc_EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1
    Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    'UserService overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                If _catelog IsNot Nothing Then _catelog.Dispose()
                If _mefContainer IsNot Nothing Then _mefContainer.Dispose()
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' The main entry point for the process
    <MTAThread()> _
    Shared Sub Main()

#If Not Debug Then
        Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
        ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New svc_EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1}
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
#Else
        Dim service = New Worker
        service.InitWork()
#End If

    End Sub

    'Required by the Component Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    ' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
    ' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  
    ' Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.ServiceName = "JCB.EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1"

    End Sub

End Class

Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting
Imports Service.Common

Public Class svc_EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1

    Private _catelog As AssemblyCatalog
    Private _mefContainer As CompositionContainer

    <Import(GetType(IServiceWorker))>
    Private Property ServiceWorker As IServiceWorker

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim catelog As AggregateCatalog = New AggregateCatalog(New DirectoryCatalog("."), New AssemblyCatalog(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase))
        _mefContainer = New CompositionContainer(_catelog)
        _mefContainer.ComposeParts(Me)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ServiceWorker.InitWork()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ServiceWorker.StopWork()
        _mefContainer.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The issue I am having is when MEF tries to run the composition on the `IServiceWorker` property it fails. Initially I though that the `IServiceWorker` was not coming through as one of the available parts in the `AggregateCatalog`

```
Dim catelog As AggregateCatalog = New AggregateCatalog(New DirectoryCatalog("."), New AssemblyCatalog(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase))
```

In order to confirm that this was a valid part I outputted then parts collection to a text file using the below code.

```
For Each p As System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition In catelog.Parts
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat(vbCrLf, p.ToString, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)

    For Each meta As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In p.Metadata
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat("Meta Data Key : ", meta.Key, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat("Meta Data Val : ", meta.Value.ToString, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    Next

    For Each exp As Primitives.ExportDefinition In p.ExportDefinitions
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat("Export Definition Contract Name : ", exp.ContractName, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    Next

    For Each imp As Primitives.ImportDefinition In p.ImportDefinitions
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat("Import Definition Contract Name : ", imp.ContractName, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    Next

    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, vbCrLf, Text.Encoding.Unicode)

Next
```

You can see from the extract below that the `Service_EPMS_OPC_6Cylinder_Zone1.Worker` part implements `IServiceWorker` in its `ExportDefinitions`

```
Service.Common.DataAccess.AuditLogger
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IAuditLogger
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDatabaseHelperFactory

Service.Common.DataAccess.DataHelper
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDataHelper
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDatabaseHelperFactory

Service.Common.DataAccess.SqlDatabaseHelperFactory
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDatabaseHelperFactory

Service.Common.Logging.ErrorLogger
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Logging.ILogger
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDataHelper

Service.Common.Network.NetworkAvailability
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Network.INetworkAvailability
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDataHelper
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Network.IRemoteServiceHost

Service.Common.Network.RemoteServiceHost
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Network.IRemoteServiceHost


Service.Common.ObjectCreation.EngineBuilder
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.ObjectCreation.IEngineBuilder
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDataHelper

Service.Common.Opc.OpcHelper
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Opc.IOpcHelper

Service_EPMS_OPC_6Cylinder_Zone1.Worker
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.IServiceWorker

Service_EPMS_OPC_6Cylinder_Zone1.ZoneProcess
Export Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.IZoneProcess
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Logging.ILogger
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IDataHelper
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Network.INetworkAvailability
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.ObjectCreation.IEngineBuilder
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.Opc.IOpcHelper
Import Definition Contract Name : Service.Common.DataAccess.IAuditLogger
```

This is what I would have expected as the `Worker` class does Export on the type `IServiceWorker`. I have commented out two additional Imports on this class just to make sure that they were not causing the issue.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting
Imports System.Threading
Imports Service.Common
Imports Service.Common.Enums
Imports Service.Common.Logging

<Export(GetType(IServiceWorker))>
Public Class Worker
    Implements IServiceWorker

    Private _thread As Thread

    '<Import(GetType(IZoneProcess))>
    'Private Property Processor() As IZoneProcess

    '<Import(GetType(ILogger))>
    'Private Property Logger() As ILogger

#Region " Service Methods"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Tear down the service
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub StopWork() Implements IServiceWorker.StopWork
        'Tear down the worker thread
        If Not _thread Is Nothing Then
            If Not _thread.Join(100) Then
                _thread.Abort()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initialise the worker thread
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub InitWork() Implements IServiceWorker.InitWork

        Dim objThreadStart As New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.StartWork)
        _thread = New Thread(objThreadStart)
        _thread.Start()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Start the worker thread functionality
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub StartWork()

        Try
            If Not Initialise() Then
                Me.StopWork()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' If Logger IsNot Nothing Then Logger.LogError(My.Settings.ApplicationID, "StartWork", ex.Message, IssueSeverity.Critical)
            Me.StopWork()
        End Try
    End Sub

#End Region

    Private Function Initialise() As Boolean

#If DEBUG Then
        RunDebugModeComposition()
#End If
        'Return Processor.InitialiseApplication()

    End Function

    Private Sub RunDebugModeComposition()

        Try
            Dim catelog As AggregateCatalog = New AggregateCatalog(New DirectoryCatalog("."), New AssemblyCatalog(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase))
            Dim container As CompositionContainer = New CompositionContainer(catelog)
            container.ComposeParts(Me)
        Catch ex As CompositionException
            Throw New ApplicationException("The composition of the application failed. Pleae check the underlying exception", ex)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

I further queryed the Composition issue with the below code

```
Try
    _mefContainer.ComposeParts(Me)
Catch ex As CompositionException
    For Each e As CompositionError In ex.Errors
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat(vbCrLf, "Description : ", e.Description, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat(vbCrLf, "Message : ", e.Exception.Message, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat(vbCrLf, "Stack Trace : ", e.Exception.StackTrace, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)

        If e.Exception.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat(vbCrLf, "Message : ", e.Exception.InnerException.Message, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(compositionErrorLog, String.Concat(vbCrLf, "Stack Trace : ", e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace, vbCrLf), Text.Encoding.Unicode)
        End If

    Next
End Try
```

This game me the below output in the text file

```
Description : Cannot set import 'Service_EPMS_OPC_6Cylinder_Zone1.svc_EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1.ServiceWorker (ContractName="Service.Common.IServiceWorker")' on part 'Service_EPMS_OPC_6Cylinder_Zone1.svc_EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1'.

Message : The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    Service.Common.IServiceWorker
    RequiredTypeIdentity    Service.Common.IServiceWorker


Stack Trace :
```

Now what I am unsure of is why the `IServiceWorker` Export that is in the MEF Catelog Parts collection is not being picked up by the `ComposeParts`. As far as I can see the Export attribute on the Worker class should match the Import on the `ServiceWorker` property in `svc_EpmsOPCService_6Cylinder_Zone1`

Any idea why this Import is not working?

EDIT:
I have refactored the code so that the 'Worker' class is called as a concrete implementation and the composition then takes place within the 'Worker' class and everything works.
Is there a limitation that you can not compose the MEF parts from the windows service component that inherits from 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase' ?

Comment: why are you still using servicebase?  PM> Install-Package TopShelf  Just moving to topshelf will probably eliminate this error.

Comment: Why am I using ServiceBase? That's the standard way to implement a Windows Service. Not all of us are able to use open source or non Microsoft technologies. Its the wonders of working in a large enterprise business.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party on this one, but i wonder if the issue is more related to how Windows registers and maintains services.  I believe the SCM or some other back end service component is locking out the resources when the service is registered.

I don't believe it is an issue with the Service base class in and of itself, it doesn't appear to be too weird, it's not static, it just extends Component, etc. Rather, i bet it's related to Services themselves and resource management.

For grins and giggles, were you using ShadowCopy for your MEF DirectoryCatalog?  If you weren't i wonder if it would have helped...some of this is speculation as i haven't had time to setup my own test bed, but it's an educated guesss from experience with both MEF and Services separately.